# Tomcat Servlet performance: StringBuilder vs. direct write

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, networking

This is one for the tomcat / network experts. I would benchmark / wireshark it but this is pretty demanding and perhaps someone knows the answer offhand.

Comparing these two methods for generating servlet output, which one would be the fastest from a user's perspective:

1. Writing direct to the servlet output stream:

   for( int i=0; i<10000; i++ ) {
       servletOutputStream.write( "a" );
       /* a little bit of delay */
   }
2. Creating a buffer and write it in one turn

   for( int i=0; i<10000; i++ ) {
       stringbuffer.append( "a" );
   }
   servletOutputStream.write( stringBuffer.toString() )

I can imagine the PROs of method 1 would be that the response can start sending stuff quickly while in method 2 the sending starts later.

On the other hand method 1 could generate more / smaller TCP packets which in turn could take longer to transmit completely?

Regards

PS: Please, don't tell me this is premature optimization. In the case at hand I have an object which offers both `toString` and `write(Appendable a)` methods. I've simply have to choose which one to use here. Additionally I find this very interesting from a theoretical point of view and regarding the general design of servlets.

**EDIT:** Thanks all for the answers. But it seems I was to unclear in my question or oversimplified my example.

I'm not worried about not buffering at all. I know that there must be buffering at least in one place in the sending queue. Probably it is in multiple places (Java,OS,Hardware). I think the real question I have is this: **When is are these buffers flushed?**

So to make it more clear lets assume we have a MTU of 1000 and sending of consecutive packets is triggered by a buffer-empty interrupt by the hardware. Then in the first case it *could* look like:

```
. packet( "a" ) //triggered by the first write( "a" ),
. packet( "aaaaaaa" ) // triggered by buffer-empty, sending the amount of "a"s which have been written in the meantime
. packet( "aaaa" ) // and so on
. packet( "aaaaaaaaaaa" )
...x1000 // or so in this example
```

While for the second case there are all 10000 bytes already available when sending starts and so the result would be:

```
. packet( "aaaa....a(x1000)" )
. packet( "aaaa....a(x1000)" )
...x10
```

Even for smaller data sizes (smaller than MTU, lets say 100 "a"s) and creating the output faster then it could be send the result *could* look like:

```
. packet( "a" ) // first write
. packet( "aaaa...a(x99) ) // all remaining data available when buffer-empty interrupt.
```

Of course all this would be quiet different if the buffer(s) where working differently. E.g. if they would be waiting for more data to send or waiting for a flush to send anything at all ... (but this in turn would slow down sending in some respect, too)

So this is what I don't know: **How exactly is this buffering within tomcat working** and what would be the the best strategy of using it?

(And I'm not worrying or expecting larger speed gains. I just like to know how things work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that the `ServletOutputStream` is actually an instance of

```
    org.apache.tomcat.core.BufferedServletOutputStream
```

which is (as the name suggests) is a buffered stream.  That will mean that it is better to write characters directly to the stream rather than assembling them in a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` and writing the result.  Writing directly will avoid at least one copy of the characters.

If it turns out that your `ServletOutputStream` is not buffered already, then you can wrap it in a `BufferedOutputStream`, and you will get the same result.

---

Assuming now that you are talking about the streams now. (Flushing a `StringBuffer` has no meaning.)

> When is are these buffers flushed?

When they are full, when you call `flush` on the stream, or when the stream is closed.

> ... and what would be the the best strategy of using it?

In general, write the data and when you are finished, close the file.  Don't flush explicitly, unless there is a good reason to do so.  There rarely is, if you are delivering ordinary HTTP responses.  (A flush is liable to cause the network stack to transmit the same amount of information by sending more network packets.  That could impact on overall network throughput.)

In the case of the servlet framework, I recall that the Servlet specification says that a `ServletOutputStream` will automatically be flushed and closed when the request/response processing is finished.  Provided that you didn't wrap the `ServletOutputStream`, you don't even *need* to close the stream.  (It does no harm though.)

Comment: Hi Stephen, please see my edit. I'm more interested in how / when these buffers are flushed. I edited my question to make it more clear what I'm after. But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

There's no doubt that writing directly to the output stream will be faster for a number of reasons:

1. The output buffer is fixed
2. The output buffer will be flushed automatically when it's full (and I'd argue that it doesn't matter *when* this happens, so stop worrying about it)
3. The output buffer will be re-used
4. Your `StringBuilder` can grow very large, taking up lots of heap space
5. Your `StringBuilder` will re-allocate its space at intervals, causing new objects to be created, data copied all over the place, etc
6. All that memory activity will create "garbage" that the GC will have to deal with

**However**

I would argue that your analysis isn't taking into account a ver important factor: detection and recovery from errors.

If you have a semi-complex procedure that your servlet is performing, it could fail at any time. If it fails after rendering half of the output, you will be unable to do any of the following things:

1. Issue an "error" HTTP status code (e.g. 500 Server Error)
2. Redirect the user to another page (error page?)
3. Show a nice error message on the screen without ruining/interrupting the page

So, even though the manually-buffered approach (based upon the `StringBuilder`) is less efficient, I believe it gives you a great deal of flexibility for handling errors.

This is more of a religious argument than anything else, but you'll find many web application programmers who would say that your servlet should produce no output at all, and the task of generating responses should be delegated to another component more suited to the task (e.g. JSP, Velocity, FreeMarker, etc.).

If you are, however, writing a servlet with an eye towards raw speed, then by all means: write directly to the output stream. It will give you the best performance in both micro-benchmarks and overall speed under load.

**EDIT 2016-01-26**

> When [are] these buffers flushed?

The servlet spec makes no guarantees about whether or not the `ServletOutputStream` is buffered or not, but not using a buffer would be a practical mistake: sending TCP packets one-character-at-a-time would certainly be awful for performance.

If you absolutely need to make sure that the response is buffered, you must use your own `BufferedOutputStream`, because the servlet container could change its implementation at any time and, as mentioned, is not guaranteed to buffer your response for you.

> How exactly is this buffering within Tomcat working?

The buffering currently implemented in Tomcat works just like buffering in the standard JDK classes: when the buffer fills, it's flushed to the lower stream and then the balance of bytes remains in the buffer after the call is made.

If you manually call `flush` on the stream, you'll force the use of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` which means that additional data will need to be sent over the wire, because there is no `Content-Length` (unless you manually set one before you start filling the buffer). If you can avoid chunked-encoding, you can save yourself some network traffic. Also, if the client knows the `Content-Length` of the response, they can show an accurate progress bar when downloading the resource. With `chunked` encoding, the client never knows how much data is coming until it's all been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you `servletOutputStream` in a `BufferedOutputStream` (unless it already is) and you don't need to worry about silly things like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use the first one. The servlet output stream is buffered, so you don't have to worry about sending it too fast. Also you allocate a new string everytime with the second one, which might impose a GC overhead overtime. Use the first one and call flush after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's already buffered, and in some cases it is written to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` so that Tomcat can prepend the Content-Length header. Don't worry about it.